# How to send email with a custom email template

Tags: magento, templates, sendmail

I am creating a template for abandoned orders.
But when I try to use the template created, the send a blank email, more the template appears in: `System/Transactional Email`

Template

The temaplate is a copy of `order_update.html` with name `test_order_update.html` in `en_US/template/email/sales/`

Config.xml - This is working

```
<global>    
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_template  module="mymodule">
                <label>Abandoned Transactions</label>
                <file>sales/test_order_update.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

Shooting - Do not load the template

```
<?php
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    $emailTemplate->loadDefault('test_order_update');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('my subject here');

    $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email');
    $name = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name');

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($name, $storeId);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($email, $storeId);

    $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = ' something';
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);

    $emailTemplate->send('myemail@gmail.com', 'name...', $emailTemplateVariables);
?>
```

Email received

```
Sender: Sales <sales@example.com>
Subject: my subject here
Content:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replacing

```
$emailTemplate->loadDefault('test_order_update');
```

with

```
$emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_template');
```

because to load a email template you have to give the tag name that you provide in the config.xml

also add following line before sending mail

```
$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
```

if your template is copy of order_update.html you also need to pass the order object as teh email parameter.